# Delete list elements above a certain threshold

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

**1. Problem statement**

Going from right to left, I want do delete all elements after they have occured `n` times. The solution I found seems to work reliably, but is rather long and uses a function, `DeleteElements`, which was only introduced in `V 13.1`.

**2. Current solution**

```
DeleteAbove[lis_, n_] /; n >= Max @ Counts @ lis := {}

DeleteAbove[lis_, n_] :=
 Module[{tal, del},
  tal = Select[Tally @ lis, Last[#] > n &];
  del = Rule @@ ReplaceAll[{a_, b_} :> {a - n, b}] @ Reverse @ Transpose @ tal;
  Reverse @ DeleteElements[Reverse @ lis, del]]
```

**3. Examples**

```
list = {1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 4, 2, 2, 5, 8, 8, 5, 5};

DeleteAbove[list, 3]
```

{1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 4, 2, 5, 8, 8}

```
DeleteAbove[{2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1}, 2]
```

{2, 2, 1, 1, 8}

**4. Questions**

- How would a nicer / shorter solution look like?
- Can this problem be solved with one of the `Sequence` - functions?

Comment: Why does `DeleteAbove[{8,8},3]` give the empty set?

Comment: In my solution, if n is equal or higher to `Max@ Counts@lis` you get many failure messages . Therefore the first definition of `DeleteAbove` . 
One could replace the empty set with a message like ' n exceeds maximum element count'.

Comment: But if `8` only occurs twice in the list, and you want to delete above `3` occurrences, surely the output should be `{8,8}`?

Comment: That's a mistake in my solution: `DeleteAbove[{8, 8}, 3]` should give `{8,8}` and not a bunch of error messages or the empty set.

Comment: @eldo in that case surely the definition should be `DeleteAbove[lis_, n_] /; n >= Max @ Counts @ lis := lis`. I.e. just return the list and do nothing (the identity operation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list = {1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 4, 2, 2, 5, 8, 8, 5, 5};

list[[Values@(Take[#,UpTo[3]]&/@PositionIndex[list])//Flatten//Union]]

(* {1,5,5,2,2,6,4,2,5,8,8} *)
```

```
list2={2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1}

list2[[Values@(Take[#,UpTo[2]]&/@PositionIndex[list2])//Flatten//Union]]

(* {2,2,1,1,8} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[takeUpTo]
takeUpTo = Module[{$a}, $a[_] = 0; Map[x |-> If[++$a[x] > #2, Nothing, x]]@#] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
takeUpTo[list, 3]
```

> ```
> {1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 4, 2, 5, 8, 8}
> ```

```
takeUpTo[{2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1}, 2]
```

> ```
> {2, 2, 1, 1, 8}
> ```

Comment: I love this. I've been programming this language for so long and stuff like this still blows my mind. I just wrote a utility where I used a clunky Association with default values for tracking counts and it never occurred to me to just instantiate a symbol like you did with $a here.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
DeleteAbove[k_List, n_Integer] := Module[{
   pos = Position[
     MapIndexed[Count[k[[1 ;; First@#2]], #1] &, k], _?(# <= n &)]
   },
  Extract[k, pos]
  ]

lists = {{1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 4, 2, 2, 5, 8, 8, 5, 5}, {2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
    8, 1}, {8, 8}};
lims = {3, 2, 3};

DeleteAbove @@@ Transpose[{lists, lims}]
```

> {{1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 4, 2, 5, 8, 8}, {2, 2, 1, 1, 8}, {8, 8}}

Answer (score 3):

```
KeepUpTo[list_, count_] := 
  DeleteCases[FoldPairList[KeepUpToStep[count], <||>, list], Null];
KeepUpToStep[n_][counts_, val_] := 
  If[
    Lookup[counts, val, 0] < n, 
    {val, Merge[{counts, <|val -> 1|>}, Total]}, 
    {Null, counts}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll call my attempt `RemoveByOccurrences`:

```
RemoveExcessOccurrences[list_, element_, maxOccurrences_] := 
Module[{count = 0}, DeleteCases[list, _?(If[# == element, count++; count > maxOccurrences, 
False] &)]]

RemoveByOccurrences[list_, maxOccurrences_] := 
Module[{elementCounts, elementsToDelete}, 
elementCounts = Tally[list];
elementsToDelete = Select[elementCounts, #[[2]] > maxOccurrences &][[All, 1]];
Fold[RemoveExcessOccurrences[#1, #2, maxOccurrences] &, list, elementsToDelete]]
```

Testing `RemoveByOcurrences`:

```
list = {1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 4, 2, 2, 5, 8, 8, 5, 5};
res = {1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 4, 2, 5, 8, 8};
list2 = {2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1};
res2 = {2, 2, 1, 1, 8};
list3 = {2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3, 5};
res3 = {2, 2, 1, 1, 8, 5, 3, 5, 3};

RemoveByOccurrences[list, 3] === res

(*True*)

RemoveByOccurrences[list2, 2] === res2

(*True*)

RemoveByOccurrences[list3, 2] === res3

(*True*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[pickUpTo]
pickUpTo = Module[{$i, mask}, 
   $i @_ = 0; 
   mask = # /. Except[List | _List, x_] :> ++$i[x];
   Pick[#, UnitStep[#2 - mask], 1]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
pickUpTo[list, 3]
```

> ```
> {1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 4, 2, 5, 8, 8}
> ```

```
pickUpTo[{2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1}, 2]
```

> ```
> {2, 2, 1, 1, 8}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[deleteExcessiveDuplicates]

deleteExcessiveDuplicates = Module[{$i}, 
   $i[_] = 0; DeleteDuplicates[#, {w, z} |-> w == z && ++$i[w] > #2]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
deleteExcessiveDuplicates[list, 3]
```

> ```
> {1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 4, 8, 8}
> ```

```
deleteExcessiveDuplicates[Alphabet[][[{2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1}]], 2]
```

> ```
> {"b", "b", "a", "a", "h"}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[dropExcessiveDuplicates]

dropExcessiveDuplicates = Module[{$i},
   $i[_] = 0;
   ReplaceAll[Except[List | _List, x_] :> If[++$i[x] > #2, Nothing, x]] @ #] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
dropExcessiveDuplicates[list, 3]
```

> ```
> {1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 4, 2, 5, 8, 8}
> ```

```
dropExcessiveDuplicates[Alphabet[][[{2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1}]], 2]
```

> ```
> {"b", "b", "a", "a", "h"}
> ```